# VBA - Automatically chosing the correct and rounded scale

Tags: vba, excel, range

I've got a struggle. I have a code that works perfectly but I have to set my own ranges (scales) in the code as you can see (cato0 to cato 8). My codes has to function on all sort of data (currency), It could be millions it could be K's. But is has to be rounded to perfect  obvious scales. If someone has an idea I can't wait to hear your point of view on the matter...

```
sub test()

  Dim Cato0 As Double, Cato1 As Double, Cato2 As Double, Cato3 As Double, Cato4 As Double, _
        Cato5 As Double, Cato6 As Double, Cato7 As Double, Cato8 As Double, Cato9 As String

    Cato0 = 0
    Cato1 = 500
    Cato2 = 1000
    Cato3 = 2500
    Cato4 = 5000
    Cato5 = 7500
    Cato6 = 10000
    Cato7 = 12500
    Cato8 = 15000
    Dim TargetRange         As Range
    Dim TotalPremium()      As Double
    Dim PremiumCount()      As Long
    Dim TotalCommission()   As Double
    Dim CellPremium()       As Double
    Dim PolNo               As Long
    Dim Cell                As Range
    Dim NOCatoI             As Integer

    NOCatoI = 9 'Number of Catogories
    PolNo = 1

    ReDim PremiumCount(1 To NOCatoI)
    ReDim TotalPremium(1 To NOCatoI)
    ReDim TotalCommission(1 To NOCatoI)


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'Set TargetRange = Range("CC2:CC" & lastRow)
    End With

    Set TargetRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("CC2:CC" & lastRow)
    For Each Cell In TargetRange

        With Cell
            If .Value <= Cato1 Then
                i = 1
                TotalPremium(i) = TotalPremium(i) + .Value
                PremiumCount(i) = PremiumCount(i) + 1
                TotalCommission(i) = TotalCommission(i) + .Offset(0, 3).Value
            ElseIf (.Value > Cato1) And (.Value <= Cato2) Then
                i = 2
                TotalPremium(i) = TotalPremium(i) + .Value
                PremiumCount(i) = PremiumCount(i) + 1
                TotalCommission(i) = TotalCommission(i) + .Offset(0, 3).Value
           ElseIf (.Value > Cato2) And (.Value <= Cato3) Then
                i = 3
                TotalPremium(i) = TotalPremium(i) + .Value
                PremiumCount(i) = PremiumCount(i) + 1
                TotalCommission(i) = TotalCommission(i) + .Offset(0, 3).Value
           ElseIf (.Value > Cato3) And (.Value <= Cato4) Then
                i = 4
                TotalPremium(i) = TotalPremium(i) + .Value
                PremiumCount(i) = PremiumCount(i) + 1
                TotalCommission(i) = TotalCommission(i) + .Offset(0, 3).Value
            ElseIf (.Value > Cato4) And (.Value <= Cato5) Then
                i = 5
                TotalPremium(i) = TotalPremium(i) + .Value
                PremiumCount(i) = PremiumCount(i) + 1
                TotalCommission(i) = TotalCommission(i) + .Offset(0, 3).Value
            ElseIf (.Value > Cato5) And (.Value <= Cato6) Then
                i = 6
                TotalPremium(i) = TotalPremium(i) + .Value
                PremiumCount(i) = PremiumCount(i) + 1
                TotalCommission(i) = TotalCommission(i) + .Offset(0, 3).Value
            ElseIf (.Value > Cato6) And (.Value <= Cato7) Then
                i = 7
                TotalPremium(i) = TotalPremium(i) + .Value
                PremiumCount(i) = PremiumCount(i) + 1
                TotalCommission(i) = TotalCommission(i) + .Offset(0, 3).Value
            ElseIf (.Value > Cato7) And (.Value <= Cato8) Then
                i = 8
                TotalPremium(i) = TotalPremium(i) + .Value
                PremiumCount(i) = PremiumCount(i) + 1
                TotalCommission(i) = TotalCommission(i) + .Offset(0, 3).Value
            ElseIf Cato8 < .Value Then
                i = 9
                TotalPremium(i) = TotalPremium(i) + .Value
                PremiumCount(i) = PremiumCount(i) + 1
                TotalCommission(i) = TotalCommission(i) + .Offset(0, 3).Value
            End If
        End With
    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet4")
        .Range("A4").Value = Cato0 & " TO " & Cato1
        .Range("A5").Value = Cato1 & " TO " & Cato2
        .Range("A6").Value = Cato2 & " TO " & Cato3
        .Range("A7").Value = Cato3 & " TO " & Cato4
        .Range("A8").Value = Cato4 & " TO " & Cato5
        .Range("A9").Value = Cato5 & " TO " & Cato6
        .Range("A10").Value = Cato6 & " TO " & Cato7
        .Range("A11").Value = Cato7 & " TO " & Cato8
        .Range("A12").Value = ">" & Cato8

        .Range("B13").Value = PolNo - 1


        .Range("C4:C12").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        '.Range("D4:D12").NumberFormat = "000.000.000.000,00"
        .Range("H4:H12").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        '.Range("E4:E12").NumberFormat = "000.000.000.000,00"

        For i = 4 To (NOCatoI + 3)
            .Range("B" & i).Value = PremiumCount(i - 3)
            .Range("D" & i).Value = TotalPremium(i - 3)
            .Range("E" & i).Value = TotalCommission(i - 3)
            .Range("H" & i).Value = TotalCommission(i - 3) / TotalPremium(i - 3) ''Error when TotalCommission = 0 and TotalPremium = 0
            .Range("C" & i).Value = PremiumCount(i - 3) / PolNo
        Next i

    End With

end sub
```

Comment: To me it is very unclear what you are asking for. What do you mean by "*has to be rounded to perfect obvious scales*". Can you give some examples?

Comment: @PeH, Like the answer below (given by Parveen Soroha) my goal is to "dynamically scales to Cat1 to Cat8".

Comment: so if your question was how to make it possible that the user can input these scales then your answer is below: `InputBox` alternatively a UserForm that asks to enter all these.

Comment: @Peh, Yeah but is it possible to do it automatically instead of the manual way. The manual way would cost too much time every time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*automatically*", should it guess or what? If you want VBA to choose the scale for you this has to follow a rule. So you need to tell which rule should be applied to find the correct scale.

Comment: VBA cannot decide for you. You need to tell VBA by which rule you scale. Finding min and max can be easy `WorksheetFunction.Min()` and `WorksheetFunction.Max()` but how would you place the scales in between?

Comment: @PEH, Yeah I mean that the VBA code extracts the data, sees the minimum and maximum of the data and than decides the value of the windows.
For instance: Dataset: 900/10.000/5.000/4.000/3.000/17.000/ 8.000/7.000. Then Vba sees the minimum (900) and maximum (17.000) and then it decides. WIndow1: [0 to 1000], Window2: [1000 to 2500], window3: [2500-5000], 4:[5000-7500], 5: [7500-10000], 6: [10000-12500], 7: [12500-15000] 8:[>15000]

Comment: but where do these window sizes come from? How would VBA find them. How does VBA know which are the correct ones?

Comment: @PEH, Yeah lol that's what I'm asking. Does somebody know a the rules to apply so VBA does understand what I'm asking?
Please forgive me for my unintentional ignorance if that's the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach could be taking the maximum of your value range and distribute the scale evenly.

So assuming your dataset is `900; 10000; 5000; 4000; 3000; 17000; 8000; 7000` and you want `8` scale values

This can be done by dividing the maximum value `17000` by the count of scale values `8` you expect and multiply that with the scale position:

- ScaleValue 0: `17000 / 8 * 0`
- ScaleValue 1: `17000 / 8 * 1`
- ScaleValue 2: `17000 / 8 * 2`
- …
- ScaleValue 8: `17000 / 8 * 8`

So we would end up with a scale like: `0; 2125; 4250; 6375; 8500; 10625; 12750; 14875; 17000`

Here is an example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim MyScale As Variant
    MyScale = GetScaleFromValues(TargetRange, 8) 'get 8 scale values from value range

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(MyScale) To UBound(MyScale)
        Debug.Print CStr(MyScale(i)) 'print out all scale values
    Next i

    'or access each scale value individually by
    Debug.Print MyScale(5) 'for the fifth scale value
End Sub

Public Function GetScaleFromValues(ValueRange As Range, Optional ScaleCount As Long = 8) As Variant
    Dim MyScale() As Double
    ReDim MyScale(ScaleCount) As Double

    Dim MaxValue As Double
    MaxValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ValueRange)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(MyScale) To UBound(MyScale)
        MyScale(i) = (MaxValue / ScaleCount) * i
    Next i

    GetScaleFromValues = MyScale
End Function
```

Comment: @pEh Thanks! Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you want to provide dynamically scales to Cat1 to Cat8. In that case you can use the "InputBox Function to provide the values to defined variables of Cat1 to Cat8.

Comment: Sroha, Thanks for your input, I know I could accomplish my goal in 'providing dynamically scales to Cat1 to Cat8' (btw thanks for the better explanation of my problem). But I am 99% sure it could be done automatically instead of an InputBox, but I don't know the way myself. I was ho[ping one of you guys dooes